# Need help in sql query to give result set based on previous version

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

i have two tables , table1 and table2.

```
table1
id  name   city        uqid
1   vikas mysore       2


table2
id  uqid    name    status
1   1   vikas   pending
1   2   Vikas   processing
```

I have a SQL query to fetch the details of table1 joined with table2

```
select table1.id,
       table1.name,
       table1.city,
       table2.status
from table1 
   left outer join table2 
     on table2.uqid = table1.uqid 
    and table2.id = table1.id
```

this will give me the result set

```
id      name     city    status
1   vikas   mysore  processing
```

how can i modify the above query to not to give us the result set until the status is set to "pass" in table2 for uqid = 1 and id = 1 ?

Comment: please anyone edit the question to appear the data in table format

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the relation between  uqid = 1,id = 1 and uniq = 2, id= 1 ?

Comment: i would like to get the result set of all ids that are in processing status present in table2 if all of its previous status are in pass status

Comment: So how to find out which record is previous? I mean if uqid is 1 then previous state and 2 current state?

Comment: the value of table1.uqid that matches table2.uqid is always the current state. any other records present in table2 for that id and less than uqid are considered as previous

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
select table1.id,
       table1.name,
       table1.city,
       table2.status
from table1 
   left outer join table2 
     on table2.uqid = table1.uqid 
    and table2.id = table1.id
where table2.status ilike 'pass';
```

If by stating that you need table2's uqid=id=1, you mean that you need both the fields to have same value then use the following.

```
select table1.id,
       table1.name,
       table1.city,
       table2.status
from table1 
   left outer join table2 
     on table2.uqid = table1.uqid 
    and table2.id = table1.id
where table2.status ilike 'pass' and table2.uqid=table2.id;
```

Suggestion: Try to normalize your tables

Comment: Add your query in code block, otherwise its difficult to read.

Comment: Was in the middle of it when you did it. Anyways, will take care of it next time

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the proper way or any other efficient way exists , but this will give you the desired result.

```
select table1.id,
   table1.name,
   table1.city,
   table2.status
from table1 
left outer join table2 
on table2.uqid = table1.uqid and table2.id = table1.id
where table1.id in(select distinct id from table2 where status like 'pass' 
                   and uqid not in(select uqid from table1))
```